# Python Dataframe new column based on conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, signals, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe consisting of a few columns of custom calculations for a trading strategy.  I want to add a new column called 'Signals' to this dataframe, consisting of 0s and 1s (long only strategy).  The signals will be generated on the following code, each item in this code is a separate column in the dataframe:

```
if:
    open_price > low_sigma.shift(1) and high_price > high_sigma.shift(1):
        signal = 1
    else:
        signal = 0
```

From my understanding, if statements are not efficient for dataframes.  In addition, I haven't been able to get this to output as desired.  How do you recommend I generate the signal and add it to the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign `df['Signals']` to the boolean condition itself, then use `astype` to convert the booleans to 0s and 1s:

```
df['Signals'] = (((df['open_price'] > df['low_sigma'].shift(1)) 
    & (df['high_price'] > df['high_sigma'].shift(1)))
    .astype('int'))
```

for example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'open_price': [1,2,3,4],
    'low_sigma': [1,3,2,4],
    'high_price': [10,20,30,40],
    'high_sigma': [10,40,20,30]})

#    high_price  high_sigma  low_sigma  open_price
# 0          10          10          1           1
# 1          20          40          3           2
# 2          30          20          2           3
# 3          40          30          4           4

mask = ((df['open_price'] > df['low_sigma'].shift(1)) 
        & (df['high_price'] > df['high_sigma'].shift(1)))
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3     True
# dtype: bool

df['Signals'] = mask.astype('int')
print(df)
```

yields

```
   high_price  high_sigma  low_sigma  open_price  Signals
0          10          10          1           1        0
1          20          40          3           2        1
2          30          20          2           3        0
3          40          30          4           4        1
```

Comment: I'm still new to Python and trying to figure all of this out.  When you say assign df['Signals'] to the condition does this mean that your code above effectively replaces the if based condition? Where in the code do I assign a "1" if the condition above is true?